# Snap to cursor on only one axis

Tags: snapping, 3d-cursor

How can i move selected edges/vertices to the cursor on only one axis?

[image]

The selected edge in the image should have the exact Y position like the cursor while retaining the X of the two vertices.

I know i can copy the Y information over to the vertices but this seems tedious. Is there a more simple solution?

Comment: Have you tried to press X while dragging?

Comment: Yes. This limits movement to one axis but doesn't give me the ability to stop at the x value of the cursor

Comment: try not use the cursor as reference: set snap element to "vertex" and while sliding the 2 vertices on X, you can snap to the reference vertex position on the other axis...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With cursor positioned as desired and vertices / edges selected scale it while choosing axis which you'd like to affect on scaling (in this case Global X):

1. Select vertices, set [Pivot Point](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/pivot_point/index.html) to 3D Cursor.
2. Press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale, then <kbd>X</kbd> to scale to 3D Cursor by X axis axis.
3. Enter amount of effect of scaling. In this case it will be 0.

[image: scaling selection to 3D Cursor GIF]

Comment: I thought about it at first, but I guess it can't be done in this situation, both vertices will be scaled on Z axis, so they will overlap.

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry, I thought he's trying to move the edge to have the same Z axis as the cursor, meaning, keeping the edge unchanged, and getting the lower vertex to the position of the cursor on Z, so scaling it wont work, I've been trying to do this, so I thought this is the same situation, sorry for that!

Comment: @Georges that example still had problems, probably it's better now (although it became really basic situation).

Comment: my question is, following your example, is it possible to move the selected face without distorting it, to be on the same value of 3D cursor Z? I mean moving it down, rather than from right to left in your gif.

Comment: @Georges aside from *Selection To Cursor (Offset)* it could be simple snapping to some geometry located where 3D Cursor is (I don't think scaling is viable solution in this case). Still if you'd like to learn more about that I think it's best to ask a new question (if such doesn't exist).