# Snap a selection to cursor when scaling or moving

Tags: mesh

Hi guys Blender noob here, I am creating some gears to 3D print for a project I'm working on. I am following the tutorial below and when I get to this part I am unable to figure out how to snap the current selection to the Z height of the cursor. Video below is at the correct time when he selects the bottom right selects the adjacent Vertice that the Extrude needs to be at and then it snaps for him but not for me hopefully it is just a shortcut key I'm missing. Any help is much appreciated, thanks

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zD4yi0KQbu8&t=1112s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for...

With cursor positioned as desired and vertices / edges selected scale it while choosing axis which you'd like to affect on scaling (in this case Global X):

1. Select vertices, set [Pivot Point](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/3d_cursor.html) to 3D Cursor.
2. Press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale, then <kbd>X</kbd> to scale to 3D Cursor by X axis axis.
3. Enter amount of effect of scaling. In this case it will be 0.

Taken from [this answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52321/snap-to-cursor-on-only-one-axis)

Comment: This is EXACTLY what it was the only difference was that instead of X I scaled to the Z Axis, but the "0" after starting the scale was EXACTLY what I needed, thank you so much, that was driving me CRAZY!